# Is there any way to check a app was installed or updated?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have already ship one version of my application. for the further versions i need do some validation for check whether it is a fresh installation or an update(I couldn't use NSUserDefaults or Document Directory because my first version already shipped).

Comment: No you cannot without checking some kind of data stored by the previous version. Can you explain why you need to detect an update?

Comment: You can surely use user defaults.

Comment: @rokoenes. we already ship app with two version (Free/Pro). now we going to add one version with In App purchase. so we come up with, remove the free app from the app store and update pro version. Im going to unlock pro features for existing paid users using this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the creation date of your documents folder. If it's prior to your 1.1 version release than it's an update.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSDate *result = [fileAttribs objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: Will this also work when you are restoring from a backup or iCloud?

Comment: @rckoenes I don't know if the attributes are saved after restore. damithn will have to check that. I'm sure there are edge cases that can break the above but it's the best (only?) way I can think of.

Comment: Totally agree, just hoped you might have some answer about it. You got my upvote.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to work. From the docs: `When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old installation. `

Comment: @Desdenova From the testing I did with Xcode and the simulator this solution works. I have no way to simulate an App update from the actual AppStore so there's a chance it won't work.

Comment: @Segev I check with the devices and solution works.but there has some issues. we have to trust system date & time, and rockoenes said restore from backup. I think this the only way to handle this.