# Detect if app was fresh installed or updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need a way to detect if user install the app from fresh, or after update.
The catch here is that version 1 of my app is already on the App Store, so I cant rely on any user default flag.
I'm now working on version 2, and I want to detect on app launch, if version 1 was installed or not.
any ideas?

Comment: this is possible if somthing is doing in your version 1

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What about people having downloaded V1, deleted, and now installed V2?

Comment: @Eiko thats fine, it still consider a fresh install of version 2, because no other previous version were installed at the moment version 2 is installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to check a app was installed or updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173269/is-there-any-way-to-check-a-app-was-installed-or-updated)

Comment: there's a reasonable solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173269/is-there-any-way-to-check-a-app-was-installed-or-updated), voting to close this question because it's a duplicate and the other post has a more helpful answer

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't make the provisions (app defaults etc), there is no other standard/default way of knowing if a previous version was installed .

However, you can still find a way to detect if previous version was installed based on whether in previous version you

1. created a folder/file in app documents/cache directory or
2. created an SQLite db or
3. sent the UUID to a a server or
4. any other code/feature which can be checked with an 'if exists' code on app launch

If you can't.. there is no other way.