# iTunesConnect: How to gracefully change a paid app to a free app with in-app-purchase?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I developed an app that charges user €3 for the download. But the sale number is way too low.

Currently I hope to change the sale model to a free-trial with in-app-purchase one. The problem is how to compensate the users who already purchased it? I prefer to upgrade all the paid users with all the in-app-purchases automatically.

Does anyone has such experience to share? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends of your mobile service structure but assuming you do not have a backend with user information stored it gets a bit more complicated.

One solution would be , in the release with In App Purchases to check if the user upgrades or if it is a fresh install. A reasonable solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22174089/3979236

If is a fresh install simply unlock the feature that would have been unlocked by the in app purchase (you cannot offer an In App purchase).

Nicolas